# Dealloc method being called prematurely

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview, dealloc

I have an `UIAlertView` with 2 buttons. But I am not to able to get its `clickedButtonAtIndex` event. The problem is because  `- (void)dealloc` method is being called prematurely, where I set the delegates to nil. Because of that the alert view button click could not be handled. What could be the reason for this.

Edit:
My code has 2 flow directions. On one flow direction, its working fine. The dealloc method is being called in the right way. There is no problem with the view being released early.

But in the second flow, this problem arises. As of now, what I understand is that I need to set the UIAlertView delegate to `[self retain]` in the cases where the view gets released prematurely. But how will I check, whether the view is released or still retained, so that I don't disturb the first flow?

I am posting the relevant portion of the code. I reckon this is where the view gets deallocated.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(actionSheet.tag == 102)
    {
        if(buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self.infoView removeFromSuperview]; 
            self.isSaveInfo = NO;
            [self.doneButton.target performSelector:self.doneButton.action withObject:self.doneButton.target];  //This is where the view is getting released.

            if([[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UploadView" owner:self options:nil])
            {
                [self.uploadView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

                [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.uploadView];
            }
            [self performSelector:@selector(RemoveView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
       }

       if(buttonIndex == 1)
       {
           [self.infoView removeFromSuperview];
           self.isSaveInfo = YES;

           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadSaveButton) name:@"callThisMethod" object:nil];

           MyInfoViewController *myInfoViewController = [[MyInfoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyInfoViewController" bundle:nil];
           self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
           [self.navigationController myInfoViewController animated:YES];
           [myInfoViewController release];
       }
   }
}


-(void)RemoveView
{
    if([MyViewController OnSave])
    {
        self.testAlert = [[[ UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:messageTitle message:messageBody delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:messageClose otherButtonTitles:nil]autorelease];
        self.testAlert.tag = 1;
        [self.testAlert show];
        [MyViewController setValue:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        self.testAlert = [[[ UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:messageTitle message:messageBody delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:messageClose otherButtonTitles:messageTryAgain, nil]autorelease];
        self.testAlert.tag = 2;
        [self.testAlert show];
    }
}

-(void)loadSaveButton
{
    [doneButton.target performSelector:doneButton.action];

    if([[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UploadView" owner:self options:nil])
    {
        [self.uploadView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.uploadView];

    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(RemoveView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
}
```

The code inside `UIActionSheet` button 0 index, is where the view is getting deallocated, where as button 1 index is working fine.

Comment: Does it make sense that the delegate goes away before the alert view? Though not truly modal, the UIAlertView looks like a modal view and is intended to be used as a modal view. From that point of view (and making a few assumptions, feel free to correct them), it is odd that the delegate (that creates the alert view?) is no longer needed (popped from the view hierarchy?) while the alert view is displayed.

Comment: I have edited the question and updated with some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, this piece of code was the problem.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(RemoveView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

Here instead of withObject:nil I should have used, withObject:self, which seems to have solved the release issue.

Answer (score 3):

If the dealloc method is being called prematurely, there's probably somewhere that you need to retain the view where you haven't. Without knowing more details of your code, though, we can't tell you where that might be.

Comment: Its a rather big class, thats why I didn't post the code. So retaining the view seems to be the right option as of now? And is retaining the view in between, a good coding practice?